# How to commit changes immediately after a linq to sql truncate

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, truncate

I have a Linq to SQL database table which I'm using ExecuteCommand to perform a truncate. Immediatedly after this truncate I need to add an initial record to the table but the code fails with a 'duplicate ID' issue, indicating the truncate wasn't immediate.

Is there a way to force the truncate to happen immediately, or to wait until all changes have been committed before I do my insert?

(additional: after the program fails, if I re-run it - the tables have been truncated and the core works as expected to insert the new row)

Comment: Can you provide your code here? if not, try `context.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Entity");`

Comment: context.SaveChanges() between the truncate and the insert ?

Comment: I'm already using almost exactly that executecommand statement and doing context.SubmitChanges() afterwards.  SaveChanges doesn't exist in Linq to SQL.  Then trying to use context.TableName.InsertOnSubmit() to add a new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncate *was* immediate but LINQ to SQL does not know what you did. It cannot interpret raw SQL. So it cannot know that all entities it has loaded in memory are now gone in the database.

The database and the DataContext's in-memory state are now out-of-sync.

The ID was duplicate in the L2S identity manager because only one entity with a given key can coexist in the same DataContext (and this absolutely makes sense). If you read the error carefully you will notice that it is not a SqlException.

The easiest solution is to use a new DataContext after the truncate was executed. More complex solutions would involve refreshing the state of the loaded entities. I'm not sure how that works so you'd need to research that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I shall try this and come back to mark up. Certainly sounds right to me!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use transactions and lock the tables you're working with.
2. Handle this in a stored procedure and call the SP from code.

Comment: Does not answer at all... Just generic advice (bad advice).